# Unable to use ClassLoader in Doctrine. No such file or directory

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am trying to use Doctrine on a linux server and am finding it difficult to start with.

I have the following folder structure

```
/var/www
init.php
/database
    /entities
        Template.php
```

The contents of init.php:

```
<?php
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Entities', __DIR__."/database");
$classLoader->register();
?>
```

Respectively the Template class is in the Entities namespace:

```
<?php
namespace Entities;

/** @Entity **/
class Template {
    ...
}
?>
```

When the class loader tries to register the classes, however, it all errors out:

> [Sun Jul 28 21:59:30 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.225] PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/database/Entities/Template.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php on line 164
>
> [Sun Jul 28 21:59:30 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.225] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/database/Entities/Template.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php on line 164
>
> [Sun Jul 28 21:59:36 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.225] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico

This is the first time I am using Doctrine and the difficulty is in debugging in the current situation. I would be thankful for your suggestions.

I have the exact same setup on Windows with the only difference being to the call:

```
    $classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Entities', __DIR__."//database//");
```

where it all works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

namespace Entities;

should be lower case

namespace entities;

and then it works fine in Linux.